# Firebase Android get value of child based on key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure in Firebase:

[image]

I would like to retrieve the value for the key "name" (which in this case would be "b"). I have knowledge of the key `-K_bWdgeYxYrdmzr67bJ`. This doesn't need to have a listener. How would I do this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This will 100% works for you.**

```
ref.child("-K_bWdgeYxYrdmzr67bJ").child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        try {
            if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                try {
                    Log.e("TAG", "" + snapshot.getValue()); // your name values you will get here
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", " it's null.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.e("onCancelled", " cancelled");
    }
});
```

Comment: What if we need to get multiple entries with different keys?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add listener to super of -K_bWdgeYxYrdmzr67bJ and get Iterable from that. It will give you Iterable and then you can get your value.

```
Iterable<DataSnapshot> dsChildData = ds.getChildren();
```

This helps you to get all your objects in super of -K_bWdgeYxYrdmzr67bJ.

To access latitude and longitude you can use this

```
for(Datasnapshot dsChild : dsChildData){
    MyModel mm = dsChild.getValue(MyModel.class);
}
```

You have to use arrayList or List to store all nodes of your model class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> friendsiterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (friendsiterator.hasNext()) {

                    DataSnapshot bdaySnapShaot = friendsiterator.next();

                    if (bdaySnapShaot.getKey().equals("latitude")) {
                            hashmap.put("latitude", bdaySnapShaot.getValue().toString());
                        } else if (bdaySnapShaot.getKey().equals("longitutde")) {
                            hashmap.put("longitutde", bdaySnapShaot.getValue().toString());
                        } else if (bdaySnapShaot.getKey().equals("name")) {
                            hashmap.put("name", bdaySnapShaot.getValue().toString());
                        }


                }


            }
```

Comment: Create a Arraylist type of HashMap just like      ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mBlockedFriendslist; and add the hashmap objects into that list and access the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
mDatabaseReport.getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                   TextView Push_Key = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_points);
                    Push_Key.setText("" + postSnapshot.getKey());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```